# TypeError: Cannot read property 'taxes_by_id' of undefined at DiscountButton.apply_discount (Odoo 14)

Tags: javascript, odoo

I installed pos & pos_discont modules on Odoo 14.

I checked Global Discounts into the configuration of POS.

I got this error when clicking on Discount button .

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'taxes_by_id' of undefined
at DiscountButton.apply_discount (http://localhost:8069/web/content/111-aca580a/point_of_sale.assets.js:1493:103)
at DiscountButton.onClick (http://localhost:8069/web/content/111-aca580a/point_of_sale.assets.js:1490:275)
```

Can someone explain to me what's this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you include your code so we can find what is wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ing

Make sure your code is updated.
I believe that you have code that is fixed by Odoo now.

On the `DiscountButton` the error cause due to this function `apply_discount` line of code,

```
var first_tax = this.pos.taxes_by_id[product.taxes_id[0]];
```

You can find the fix here, [[FIX] point_of_sale: discount product with tax](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/b389dcabf49fd05c5239d68fd26ef4239963a7e5)